# How to correctly use controllers helper modules in Rails, and how to connect between those helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, module

I'm trying to call a method in one controller helper (a module) from another controller helper. It seems to be not possible, even if that method is under the `module_function`.

I guess I'm missing a fundamental principle in Ruby since I'm pretty newbie. Also it feels like I'm missing the point of how to write right OOP under Rails.

**Update**: here is an example:

I have `FirstController` and `SecondController`, and helper module for each

```
module FirstHelper
  module_function

  def methodA
    ...
  end
end


module SecondHelper
  def methodB
    FirstHelper.methodA
  end
end
```

The call for `FirstHelper.methodA` from `SecondHelper` is returning an error:

> undefined method `methodA' for SecondHelper:Module

Comment: could u be more specific on what you want to do, an example would be great :D

Comment: Should not be a problem to call one helper's methods from an other helper's method. Can you please post you controller and helpers to take a closer look?

Comment: I just copied your code (with trivial mods) and I don't see a problem... module FirstHelper

  module_function
  def methodA
    "Hello there"
  end
end

module SecondHelper
  module_function
  def methodB
    FirstHelper.methodA
  end
end

puts SecondHelper.methodB
=> Hello there

Comment: Did you "include" your first module inside your second module [like this](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/)?

Answer (score 0):

A module is a collection of methods and constants. It basically provides a namespace and prevents name clashes. You need to include or extend your First module inside your Second module.

Include is for adding methods to an instance of a class and Extend is for adding class methods. [Read this for more information](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) or [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm). In your case you can do something like this:

```
module FirstHelper
  def self.methodA
    ...
  end
end

module SecondHelper
  include FirstHelper
  def methodB
    FirstHelper.methodA
  end
end
```

Comment: defining module method will make it inaccessible within a view context.

Answer (score 0):

Helper methods are instance methods and cannot be accessed via module, but only vie classes they are included in. All the helpers are included within the view context object, so you should be able to access them simply by name:

```
module SecondHelper
  def methodB
    methodA
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use require instead of include it will work

```
module FirstHelper
  class << self
    def methodA
      ...
    end
  end
end


require 'lib/first_helper'
module SecondHelper
  def methodB
    FirstHelper.methodA
  end
end
```